Український відповідник до "bog-standard approach", це "низькосортний підхід"?
Знов займаюсь дубляжем, і вже перевірив deepL, google translator, reverso context (нажаль напрямок English - Ukrainian - там ніякий), Meriam Webster і все не те.
Повне речення таке (лекція з філософії):

Then, second, there are various kinds of bog-standard approach
sub-philosophical forms of materialism.

Тобто мені пропонують в цілому два варіанти:

Тоді, по-друге, існують різні види підходів болотного стандарту,
субфілософські форми матеріалізму.

або

Тоді, по-друге, існують різні види стандартного підходу до
субфілософських форм матеріалізму.

Але в українській мові я не чув "підход болотного стандарту" а "стандартний підхід" теж не передає навантаження ("болотяний" хіба це "стандартний" ?).
Я думаю треба "низькосортний" взяти, тоді вийде:

Тоді, по-друге, існують різні види низькосортних підходів до
субфілософських форм матеріалізму.


Bog-standard — completely ordinary, without anything special added. Звичний/звичайний/стандартний/класичний/відомий підхід.

Тут, відповідно до контексту, «застарілий метод/підхід» або «архаїчний підхід».

@RomanMikhol нижче я написав чому «застарілий» не підходив, дякую

Також, «замшілий»

Але не «низькосортний»

Враховуючи синоніми у словниках (наприклад, Cambridge Dictionary), слушним варіантом виглядає старомодний (підхід, стандарт тощо):

Також, по-друге, існують різноманітні старомодні погляди на субфілософські форми матеріалізму.

Зауваження. Із тексту запитання не є зрозумілою ваша методика перекладу саме як перекладача (більш дослівний переклад vs. більш вільний). Запропонований мною варіант, вочевидь, спирається на вільну методику перекладу, де дослівністю можна пожертвувати на користь легкості сприйняття цільовою аудиторією.

дякую за відповідь, тепер мені здається що посередній по сенсу підійде більше всього, виходячи зі списку синонімів які я побачив у Cambridge Dictionary. старомодний це як old fashioned і він по сенсу не підходить адже там іде мова про те що виникли нові форми матеріалізму які спиралися на результати різноманітних відкриттів у науці (і мішали це з Ведами наприклад)


різні форми суб-філософського матеріалізму.

Я не перекладач, моє хоббі вивчення Ніцше вже 4 роки читаю, слухаю лекції (німецьку я не знаю на такому рівні щоб це робити - тож доводиться англійською). І тепер - 7 годинний цикл лекцій, який я переслухав 10+ разів - нарізаю на короткі відео, і дублюю їх українською. І викладаю на декількох каналах - для себе і можливо ще для когось. Якось так.
Ніцше за освітою був не філософом, він був історичним філологом, експертом з історії грецької та латинської мов. Тож чому б і не мені це робити

відео 1:43 зайняло десь 2-3 години :) але без вашої допомоги було б гірше, а так встиг перезалити з уточненим перекладом!!

Є у нас така стара, ще совіцького періоду, ідіома: квадратно-гніздовий [підхід]. Означає максимальну стандартність і типовість, часто навіть форсовану.

Цікаве. Було б добре побачити якісь приклади ужитку, бо в словниках нічого такого не знайшов. Але звучить логічно.

@Yola це сленг мабуть, в літературу не попало зрозуміло чому (цензура)

@Yola в словниках дійсно нема, але чув/бачив цю фразу дуже часто. Настільки часто, що я, відверто кажучи, дуже здивований тому, що не можу її знайти у такому значенні. Можливо дійсно якийсь локальний сленг (але в інтернеті бачив її використання людьми з усього пост совку).

Пошукав російською і дійсно, є таке. Через те що воно таке поширене у московитів, я б намагався його не вживати у нас.
